# Bind Variable When Creating Table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, bind-variables

I'm trying to create a table that is filtered by a variable date, depending on the current date. Though I'm fairly new to Oracle and PL/SQL, I have already successfully written a number of "high beginner" PL/SQL procs. But I wonder if I'm taking the right approach using a variable to accomplish my goal. A simplified version of what I want to do:

Create Table myTable as 
Select * from oldTable where
effective_date is > variabledate

Perhaps this is better accomplished using a case statement within the query itself instead of using the case statement to create a variable and then using the variable in the query. But I'm thinking a variable would be more streamlined, easier to read, and possibly run faster.

I've googled and searched, but most of what I find tries to tell me *how* to write it, rather than if my approach is the most efficient.

Any thoughts/suggestions greatly appreciated!

Comment: you would need to learn a more complex solution using pipelined functions. You can create a table at runtime using execute immediate but having a table that updates itself based on a variable is not possible.  Why not just create a cursor using the variable and fill a global temp table?

Comment: Creating a table at runtime is unusual anyway. Is it to hold temporary data - in which case a global temporary table or collection is probably more appropriate? Another thought is that if the variable is 'depending on the current date' in a predictable way, e.g. `trunc(sysdate) -5`, you could have a view that incorporates that filter, perhaps. Depends what your end goal is though, and where/how you plan to use your new table. (If it's less predictable you could use a context to parameterise a view, but again depends what you're doing...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. The answers are a bit over my head, though they give me something to research and learn with. I've not used cursors before, so I will be investigating that. To be more descriptive, this is, indeed, a temporary table, and the variable date is quite predictive. Essentially, I am writing a job that will always be used at the end of a given year to manipulate data active after the first of the coming year. However, it is also possible that this will be run again in January to gather up the stragglers.

Comment: So will the data that exists at the point you run it need to be preserved, beyond the lifetime of the job/session? I also don't think anyone will be able to assess the efficiency of your approach - not sure what it's being compared against really.

Comment: It will not need to be preserved. The issue for me is that I will run this job against several permanent tables which I will join, and each table contains tens of millions of records, and my predecessors do/did not write very efficiently--jobs have run for hours before being streamlined to run in 40 mins, etc--so there is little example to follow. You may be correct in your assessment about this being too vague. But you've given me some things to think about, which is really what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try too use dynamic SQL within your procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name (variabledate DATE) IS

   v_sql_stmt VARCHAR2(1000);

 BEGIN

   v_sql_stmt = 'Create Table myTable as Select * from oldTable where effective_date is > :bind_variabledate';

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  v_sql_stmt USING variabledate;

 END;
```

PS. it is not advisable to use dynamic SQL because it is prone to SQL injection and its not easy to debug, you really need to know what you're when using it. with that being said, it is a powerful feature to use when manipulating data at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that is how I have it written :-) I'm just not sure it is the most efficient approach and was looking for a quick and dirty way to find out what those more experienced would do :-) Thank you!